# Garageband sound files default to 6 seconds in length

Tags: macos, mac, audio, garageband

I am trying to edit a clip in GarageBand which only results in a 2 second clip. However, GarageBand insists on appending an extra 4 seconds of "dead air" when I export. The full length clip isn't even 6 seconds.

What gives?

Answer (score 3):

Turn on the Cycle Region button ([image]) and stretch the yellow bar to exactly encompass the length you wish exported. That should export that specific length without the added silence.

Comment: A downvote and no comment? Boo!

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted this -- this is (counter-intuitively) the best way to export <5-second clips from GB.  I have the same need, and this actually works great (and is faster than cutting/exporting/undoing like I was doing before -- now just slide the loop over, export, slide, export... no cutting needed).

Comment: I should clarify -- I am recording lots of words at once, so I record in one take then go back and export each word rather than individually recording each word, which would take forever.  Using the loop "hack" saves me tons of time for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the clip from the end of the audio then delete the dead-air part.

Answer (score 0):

There's a purple triangle in the ruler in the top of the Garageband window. Dragging that will set the length of the project, and probably also the length of the file GB outputs.